# how to match '\u' codes for all the emojis with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, special-characters

I want to find match all the strings which will have emojis in the form of **\u** codes. I'm trying with below regexp but is not working.

```
/([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2694-\u2697]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDD5D])/g
```

But, it is not detecting. I want to match and get

```
\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04
```

these type of characters.

Comment: Where's you input string? And how should be your expected output?

Comment: I don't know about the unicode codepoints, but your regex could be written in a single character class which would include multiple ranges and single codepoints (e.g. `[\uE000-\uF8FF\uD83C\uDC00-\uDFFF ... ]`)

Comment: I think you should protect '\' with a backslash character, first. Don't know what's the input string and what's the expected output, but maybe this helps: `/(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to match emojis in the format `\uXXXX` using Regex, you can use  **[this Regex](https://regex101.com/r/vFofRM/1)**:

```
/\\u[a-z0-9]{4}/gi
```

This is a simple Demo:

```js
const regex = /\\u[a-z0-9]{4}/gi;
const str = `This is a pragraph \\ud83d having  some emojis like these ones:

\\ude04

\\ud83d

\\ude04

Have you seen them?

\\ud83d\\ude04

Great!

`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

The regex you wrote won't work because you were not escaping the `\`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm gettting spaces between the emojis. https://jsfiddle.net/ofr41m8h/1/. I have added an example here. But they are not rendering as emojis.I will get like "\u" format but they are rendering in my browser.

Comment: @user515 I don't get it? Where are seeing the spaces?