# How can I replace '\U' using regular expressions?

Tags: r, regex, string, emoji, stringr

The question is pretty simple. I'm trying to replace `"\U"` throughout a vector of strings, and for this I'm using the package `{stringr}`, but I'm having issues matching the pattern.

```r
text <- "\U0001f517"

stringr::str_detect(text, "\U")
#> Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\U"

stringr::str_detect(text, "\\U")
#> Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
#>   Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern. (U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE, context=`\U`)

stringr::str_detect(text, "\\\U")
#> Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\\\U"

stringr::str_detect(text, "\\\\U")
#> FALSE

stringr::str_detect(text, "\\\\\U")
#> Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\\\\\U"

stringr::str_detect(text, "\\\\\\U")
#> Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
#>   Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern. (U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE, context=`\\\U`)

stringr::str_detect(text, "\\\\\\\U")
#> Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\\\\\\\U"

# ... you get the idea
```

As far as I can tell, this issue is because the regex engine sees `"\U"` as indicating the beginning of a new hex code, as indicated by the first error. Other characters work fine:

```r
text <- "\a0001f517"

stringr::str_detect(text, "\a")
#> TRUE
```

I've seen other questions around this issue, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425679/how-to-match-u-codes-for-all-the-emojis-with-regexp), but still can't get this to work. Can anyone give me a working regex for this?

Comment: ``\U`` in ``text <- "\U0001f517"`` is not a separate char sequence, it is part of the Unicode character code point notation. `text` is in fact ``. ``"\a"`` is a single character, `\u0007` (run ``"\a" == '\x07'`` that outputs "TRUE").

Comment: Aha! Think I understand. So I would actually need the original string to be something like `"\\U0001f517"` then?

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your question but perhaps the following post can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/replace-single-backslash-in-r

Comment: @user16949460 No, it is not about replacing backslashes.

Comment: `library(utf8)` and then `utf8_encode(text)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you, that's perfect! If you'd like to write up that as a standalone answer I'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\U` in your `text <- "\U0001f517"` is not a separate char sequence, it is part of the Unicode character code point notation. The *literal text* in the `text` variable is in fact , you can easily check that using `cat(text)`.

On the contrary, `"\a"` is a single character (a ["Bell" character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character)) that can also be written as `"\u0007"` or `"\x07"` (run `"\a" == '\x07'` and you will see that the output is `TRUE`). See more about [*string escape sequences* syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences).

In R, to get the underlying string literal as a literal string, you can use

```r
text <- "\U0001f517"
cat(text)
## =>  

library("utf8")
text <- utf8_encode(text)
cat(text)
## => \U0001f517
```